# Evaluating iText7 using C#

Tags: itext7

Evaluating iText7 and trying to create a PDF in Memory and then writing the contents of that stream back to the client or saving the stream out to a physical file. I am using the [this link](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side) as a guide.

My code snippet

```
1  pdfMemoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
2  pdfMemoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
3  pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfMemoryStream);
4  pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
5  document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER, true);
6  document.Add(new Paragraph("Testing"));
7  document.Close();
8  var fstream = new FileStream(@"C:\publish\iTextQuoteM.pdf", FileMode.Create);
9  pdfMemoryStream.WriteTo(fstream);
10 pdfMemoryStream.Flush();
11 pdfMemoryStream.Close();
```

Line 9 will throw an `Cannot access a closed Stream` exception that makes sense but if I remove line 7 then the pdf created is not valid and not viewable. I have tried to flush the `pdfWriter` and the document but that did not help.

Obviously I have something wrong or a misunderstanding and any help appreciated.

Comment: *"I am using the this [link](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side) as a guide."* - that link leads to a page with iText 5 examples while you are evaluating iText 7. As the iText 7 API is a complete overhaul, chances are slim that that link helps you...

Answer (score 5):

The `PdfWriter` constructor accepts `System.IO.MemoryStream` so you can do the following to write a PDF to a `MemoryStream` and return a byte array:

```cs
byte[] result;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    var document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER, true);
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Testing"));
    document.Close();

    result = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\publish\iTextQuoteM.pdf", result);
```